# Perforce: Can I put a 'watch' on a file, so that I am notified when the file changes?

Tags: version-control, perforce

I want to get notifications when new changes are made to a file in Perforce.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are running the [p4 review daemon](https://community.perforce.com/s/article/2920), you just add the file to your "reviews" in your p4 user.

```
# A Perforce User Specification.
#
#  User:        The user's user name.
#  Email:       The user's email address; for email review.
#  Update:      The date this specification was last modified.
#  Access:      The date this user was last active.  Read only.
#  FullName:    The user's real name.
#  JobView:     Selects jobs for inclusion during changelist creation.
#  Password:    If set, user must have matching $P4PASSWD on client.
#  Reviews:     Listing of depot files to be reviewed by user.

User:   you

Email:  you@yourcompany.com

Update: 2012/05/01 11:08:18

Access: 2012/05/17 11:02:27

FullName:   Your Name

Password:   ******

Reviews:
    //depot/directory/...
    //depot2/dir2/file_to_review.cpp
```

Comment: This solution looks right based on the link and example. Although, I don't have privileges to use this. For now, I have put a watch in code-collaborator's preferences (as we use this tool for our code reviews).

Comment: What kind of notification will I receive if I implement this? An email notification? I have implemented this but have not seen a notification of any kind.

Comment: It should be an email, make sure the Perforce admin followed the steps in the link correctly, and that it's working.

Comment: Consider editing your answer to explain how to edit your p4 user information.  For example, running `p4 user` from the command-line.

Answer (score 2):

main menu => tools => administration => select your user row in user group window => edit [selected name should be an option if row selected] => form tab => add file or branch to reviews text field (using depot path), make sure your email is correct in email field

According to docs => "Enter the depot path to the files that you want to watch for any changes. You will receive an email notification to alert you whenever any file you have subscribed to in the Reviews field has been modified."
See: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4v/Content/P4V/configuring.user.html